# GPG plugin for Outlook for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, gnupg, microsoft-outlook-2011

Are there any GPG plugins for Outlook 2011 for Mac? I searched the web, but the only thing I was able to find was GPGol which is apparently only available for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

It's 2014 and the answer is still basically no. The only real choices are the native Apple Mail application or Thuderbird.